# Print MySQL table values using Java

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am trying to print table values from database in Java. I have created connection successfully and was able to create a table as well. But I am having trouble with printing the table values.

try

```
        {

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs;
            String getValues =
                    "SELECT * " + 
                    "FROM EMPLOYEE" /*+ this.tableName*/ + " ; ";
                    //this.executeUpdate(conn, getValues);

            rs = stmt.executeQuery(getValues);

            String printValues = rs.getString(???Want to print all the table values);


            System.out.println(printValues);


            System.out.println("Values Retrived");
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Could not get values from table");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to loop your result set using a while loop.  Example below:

```
    public static ObservableList<Customer> search_ForDropDown(String searchQuery){
    MysqlDataSource dataSource = CurrentServer.getDataSource();
    ObservableList<Customer> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    data.clear();

    try {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER LIMIT 5";

        Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);     

        while (rs.next()) {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.setID(rs.getInt("id"));
            customer.setPhoneNumber(rs.getString("phoneNumber"));
            customer.setEmailAddress(rs.getString("emailAddress"));

            data.add(customer);
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Correct. I did end up using a loop. I read through the documentation of ResultSet. It points at a row of a table, so to go through each row, I would have to use a loop. It loops until there is a next() row and if there is then it prints out the values from the column of that row.